# Does rest framework @action kwargs replace class values or not?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have tried to search the answer for this question on rest framework docs or stackoverflow but I have not been able to find it.

Suppose a rest framework viewset:

```
class MyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @action(
        detail=True,
        permission_classes=[],
        authentication_classes=[],
    )
    def extra_action(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response()
```

in this case, the `extra_action` action will have no permission nor authentication classes or will have the ones defined at class level? what happens if I override the `get_permissions` method?

```
class MyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_permissions(self):
        permission_classes = self.permission_classes[:]
        if self.action == 'extra_action':
            permission_classes.append(MyPermissionClass)

        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

    @action(
        detail=True,
        permission_classes=[],
        authentication_classes=[],
    )
    def extra_action(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response()
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`self.permission_classes[:]` results in the permissions you have set on your action. In this case, it results in `[]` since you have left it empty.

From your code, `get_permissions` method will check for `IsAuthenticated` for all the actions but for `extra_action` action only `MyPermissionClass` will be checked.